# google bot and access.log file size

Tags: file, filesize

I have a dilema.

While I access URL by:

curl -sD  -L -A "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" http://www.example.com/product1 
it gives me size 36898

when I access URL by:
curl http://www.example.com/product1 
it gives me size 36898

but access.log shows when googlebot accesses the same url size 8275

Any idea why is it and possible idea how to fix it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like it is a Google Bot related problem. Probably, the bot is configured to drop the connection after first 8K bytes read. Obviously, it does not need your files.

Comment: @madhead I'll second that!

Answer (score 0):

Well I would appreciate a bit more interest rather than just an answer which does not create of any input to the subject.
I managed to answer it myself.
The difference of file length was due to the fact that Googlebot obtained gzipped version (hence 8275) of the file but curl was accessing unzipped version (36898).